# Building GNATCOLL in an Alpine Linux Docker Container

Tags: docker, ada, alpine-linux, gnat, musl

I can't seem to get GNATCOLL to compile in an Alpine Linux based Docker Container.

My container so far is:

```
FROM alpine:edge

# Add extra repositories
RUN echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing' >> /etc/apk/repositories; \
    echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community' >> /etc/apk/repositories; \
    echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main' >> /etc/apk/repositories;

RUN apk add --no-cache build-base coreutils curl-dev gcc-gnat git gmp-dev openssl

# Bootstrap GPRBuild
RUN git clone https://github.com/AdaCore/xmlada.git; \
    git clone https://github.com/AdaCore/gprbuild.git; \
    cd gprbuild; ./bootstrap.sh --with-xmlada=../xmlada; \
    cd ..; \
    rm -rf xmlada gprbuild
```

This works fine and gets me a container with a working GNAT GPR based Ada development environment. The issue comes when I try to install GNATCOLL in this container.

Running `docker run -i -t <built_image>` the following occurs:

```
/ # git clone https://github.com/AdaCore/gnatcoll-core.git
<Typical git clone output>
/ # cd gnatcoll-core/
/gnatcoll-core # make setup
/gnatcoll-core # make
gprbuild -p -m --target=x86_64-linux  -j0 -XGNATCOLL_MMAP=yes -XGNATCOLL_MADVISE=yes -XGNATCOLL_VERSION=0.0 -XGNATCOLL_OS=unix -XBUILD=PROD  -XLIBRARY_TYPE=static -XXMLADA_BUILD=static -XGPR_BUILD=static \
        -XGNATCOLL_MMAP=yes -XGNATCOLL_MADVISE=yes -XGNATCOLL_VERSION=0.0 -XGNATCOLL_OS=unix -XBUILD=PROD gnatcoll.gpr
Setup
   [mkdir]        object directory for project GnatColl
   [mkdir]        library directory for project GnatColl
gnatcoll.gpr:24:06: unknown project file: "gpr"
make: *** [Makefile:128: build-static] Error 4
```

Based on the discussion in https://github.com/AdaCore/gnatcoll-core/issues/30 I checked my gprbuild version:

```
/gnatcoll-core # gprbuild --version
GPRBUILD Pro 18.0w (19940713) (x86_64-alpine-linux-musl)
Copyright (C) 2004-2016, AdaCore
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
See your AdaCore support agreement for details of warranty and support.
If you do not have a current support agreement, then there is absolutely
no warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
PURPOSE.
```

So it would seem that gprbuild for musl is woefully out of date, leading to an inability to build GNATCOLL. Is there any way to get a more up-to-date version of gprbuild for musl-c? If not is there any other way to get GNATCOLL installed?

Comment: I would not expect that version to be correct given the fact that you clone it directly from the GitHub repository. A hint of why the version is stated as it is can be found in the comments of file ```gpr-version.ads```, just before the beginning of the package spec.

Comment: It seems as though you are right, though it doesn't explain why I can't build gnatcoll.

Comment: It seems more likely that GPRbuild cannot find the project ```gpr.gpr``` when building GNATCOLL. This project file is located in the ```gpr``` directory of the GPRbuild repository (see [here](https://github.com/AdaCore/gprbuild/tree/master/gpr)). You might want to add the location of the ```gpr.gpr``` project to the the environment variable ```GPR_PROJECT_PATH``` (and use ```export ``` to make it visible to child processes). See also [Importing Projects](https://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug/gnat_project_manager.html#importing-projects) in the GPR Tools manual.

Comment: On second thought, you might also want to check if ```gpr.gpr``` was not already installed somewhere along with the GPRbuild executable. In that case you could also use that version.

Comment: I checked that and indeed no `gpr.gpr` was installed. I tried using the one in the project but it re-uses some build variables. In particular gnatcoll uses `-XBUILD=PROD` but gprbuild's `gpr.gpr` source file uses `-XBUILD=production` so they aren't compatible. There must be some other way to get the desired `gpr.gpr` file, but running `make install` in the gprbuild project doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: Nevermind, I've solved it... I'll post an answer shortly, just need to clean up my solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is that `./bootstrap.sh` in gprbuild doesn't install everything, it just creates a bare minimum gprbuild installation. Additionally it does not build gprlib, which is necessary for gnatcoll and also has to be installed.

The required steps are:

```
# As before...
git clone https://github.com/AdaCore/xmlada.git
git clone https://github.com/AdaCore/gprbuild.git
cd gprbuild; ./bootstrap.sh --with-xmlada=../xmlada

# New: build and install xmlada
cd ../xmlada; ./configure && make && make install

# New: build and install gprbuild fully
cd ../gprbuild
export GPR_PROJECT_PATH=/usr/local/share/gpr
make prefix=/usr/local setup && make all && make install

# New: build and install gprlib
make libgpr.build && make libgpr.install
```

With these additions I was able to build gnatcoll as specified in its project.

Comment: After wasting many hours, this answer saved the day.  Thanks!